Should I put down my degree if I don't plan to use it?
My background (Descending order):

Associate's degree in computer science with a concentration in Software development
2 years' experience as a Robotic Process Automation Engineer at a law firm
1 year of experience as an administrative assistant at a Tire company
1 year experience as a Rehabilitation CNA
1 year of experience as a medication Aide.

I am currently going for my bachelor's, but I need a part time position to bring in extra money in my household. I chose to go for an associate in addition to my bachelor's because I wanted the option to stop and get a job if needed. I've applied for 20-30 part time positions from gas station attendants to part time administrative assistant positions. My university doesn't have any open work study positions.
Should I be listing my associates if it doesn't apply to the job I am applying for?
Does it hurt my chances if I add this piece of paper to the list of accomplishments? I've not been in the room that decides what criteria to hire someone from, so I am very unsure.
Additional information requested:

I'm in Utah, US


Country helps to answer the question.

@DogBoy37 I'm in the US, more specifically Utah.

Normally I say always go with honesty.
I will throw an exception to that rule. If you are going for what would be considered a low level blue collar or certain entry level jobs, leave off the higher education.

I am not dinging Gas Station Attendants, etc. The world needs all jobs.
Having high level education is a red flag for a job that has no use past high school. It makes it very clear that you aren't sticking around long and to not hire you.

For example: I wouldn't hire a receptionist candidate with a PHD.

That seems like solid advice, but wouldn't an employer just ask how much longer I have in school? I figure a way for me to spin it in an interview is that you're getting an educated worker that can be committed to you for at least a year. I guess if I can't even make it to the interview stage its a problem...

@DogBoy37 I mean if it is a PhD in philosophy, etc... I don't think it does.

@CadeBray - Consider it from the employers view point. A true entry level job (Conv Store, Fast Food, etc.), they really don't expect long term. But do I want to put out thousands in training for a position for somebody that I am certain is short term. The gig economy has filled in that vaccum for a lot of people.

Yes, put your Associates degree on your resume.
Anything that helps you stand out from the usual candidates can only work in your favor. If you had a PhD, it would raise some questions - but an Associates explains WHY you want the parttime job (so you can continue your degree), and also shows that you have a basic understanding of how to communicate.
Take the excellent advice in this thread of networking - talk to people. Also, visit a staffing agency; with an Associates degree, they may be able to find you some part-time admin work.

The key with a lot of lower level jobs is applying at the right time.  If you walk in to apply, right after someone quits, you will get the job.  Managers do not have the time to call past applicants or go through stacks of resumes.
Its all about pounding the pavement, just don't apply online go in and talk to the manager.  Doing such shows a degree of dedication that most applicants do not display.

I know of someone who left off some very high qualifications to get a lowly job in a government office, finally found a job around kids school time etc.
After a couple of years she applied for promotion, to be told "you have the attitude, but not the qualifications to allow us to promote you".
So, she then produced the higher qualifications and evidence of serious experience... She got the promotion (and several others), BUT there were some really pointed discussions about the omissions on her first application - leaving things off is not appreciated...

None of the positions I plan to hold part time will be used as a steppingstone to my future career. I plan to omit any part time position I get from my future resumes experience. Is the moral of your answer that if I plan to make a career out of any of my part time positions I should be completely truthful?

I was simply asking for clarification on the moral you were imparting. It could have been you were implying to include the degree because you don't know where the career will take you and it could create headaches later. It wasn't clear that you were saying I should continue with applying without a degree because it felt like a warning of what could happen if you do. People have various perspectives and interpret your answers in numerous ways. Thank you for your input and clarification.
